# Making Julia find files in the LOAD_PATH

Tags: julia

I want to help Julia find my .jl file by modifying the `LOAD_PATH` variable:

```
julia> readdir()
1-element Array{String,1}:
 "test.jl"

shell> cmd /c type test.jl
# Test.jl
module Test
export f
f() = println("hi")
end

julia> push!(LOAD_PATH,pwd());

julia> import Test
ERROR: ArgumentError: Module Test not found in current path.
Run `Pkg.add("Test")` to install the Test package.
 in require(::Symbol) at .\loading.jl:365
```

The first call to `readdir()` proves that I have a file called test.jl in my current directory.  The following shell call shows that this file contains a module called Test.  The next call to `push!(LOAD_PATH,pwd());` puts the current directory in `LOAD_PATH`.  But even with the current directory in `LOAD_PATH`, Julia still can't find the `Test` module in test.jl.

What's wrong?

Comment: @Gnimuc The linked page suggests using `include` first.  However, I cannot successfully include a file unless my working directory contains that file, even if the file's directory is in LOAD_PATH.  If this is really the solution, then what is LOAD_PATH good for at all?

Comment: `LOAD_PATH` is used for loading library/project code, a common use case is to push your daily working path in .juliarc.jl and load it automatically every time you start a REPL. `include` is used for interactively loading code from REPL. Note that, when using `LOAD_PATH`, the filename should be exactly the same as the module name(case-sensitive), your error comes from here. but with `include`, you can use any filename you prefer.

Comment: To clarify, if your module is named "Test", the file must be named "Test.jl" instead of "test.jl".

Comment: @Gnimuc Your point about the module name matching the file name is really what I was looking for (and that info is not contained in the linked page).  I'll accept that if you post it as an answer.

Comment: @JeffreySarnoff strictly speaking, this is not a mandatory rule, just a convention, but is indeed the solution in OP's use case ;).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error was talking about something concerning `require`. As the doc says:

> Given the statement using `Foo`, the system looks for `Foo` within `Main`. If the module does not exist, the system attempts to `require("Foo")`, which typically results in loading code from an installed package. ... `require` is **case-sensitive** on all platforms, including those with case-insensitive filesystems like macOS and Windows.

and the reason is clear: `require` couldn't find a file named `Test` in `LOAD_PATH`. So we need to make the file name matching the module name, but this is just a convention, not a mandatory rule. What will happen if someone mistakenly runs `using test`?

```
julia> push!(LOAD_PATH,pwd())
julia> using test
WARNING: requiring "test" in module "Main" did not define a corresponding module.
julia> whos()
                          Base  34427 KB     Module
                          Core  12386 KB     Module
                          Main  41296 KB     Module
                          Test   1837 bytes  Module
```

The result shows that we've loaded the file `test.jl` and the module(`Test`) in it, but not actually `using/import` the module. This is a respected behavior since we used a wrong module name, which is also the reason why julia complained in the warning. In this case, `using test` is equivalent to `include("test.jl")`, but I highly recommend you to follow the convention and do not use this behavior.

BTW, `require` became generally case-sensitive after [this PR](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/13542). A side-effect is your `LOAD_PATH` should also be case-sensitive, this will be fixed by [this PR](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/19291) in julia-0.6.